# flynt wordpress site builder not outputting data on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

As i started to use flynt as my wordpress theme. I run into issue while using shortcode. How i can call the shortcode in the theme ?

#flynt #flyntwp #startertheme #wordpress

If you guys have any documentation for flynt, please send it to me.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [share what you have managed to produce so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"), so that the community can help you overcome the difficulties you are experiencing.